# Actionscript in HTML code after EOL enforcement of flash player

Tags: html, css, actionscript-3

Flash player EOL is in force. I want to use some actionscript commands in my HTML code. Will it work in all browsers or is it unsafe because of the EOL enforcement? The actionscript contains embedded fonts and a background movie, which I used to use for making dynamic templates. Is it safe even to use and embedded in a HTML code in 2021?  What about CSS codes in html?

**Edited:**
For example I can call an actionscript function from my HTML like so:
`<A HREF="asfunction::functionname"> invoke the function</A>`
But is it still safe to use after the EOL?

Comment: Your question is not an **algorithmic** question thus out of **StackOverflow**'s scope. It also doesn't provide a sufficient amount of information to answer it. **ActionScript** does not work in browsers as is, **EOL** or not. **ActionScript** is a scripting language that compiles (with or without the **FLA** source) to **SWF** file, which is **Flash** Application that could be deployed in a number of ways. One of these ways (also, one of the original uses of **Flash**) is running it with **Flash Plugin** for browsers. It is **Flash Plugin** that is no longer available normally due to **EOL**.

Comment: For example I can call an actionscript function from my HTML like so: <A HREF="asfunction::functionname"> invoke the function</A> But is it still safe to use after the EOL?

Comment: That does not work in HTML and never did. That **asfunction** thing was the way to make clickable links in text fields **inside** Flash Applications long ago before AS3 was introduced: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/flash-8-cookbook/0596102402/ch07s15.html

Comment: @Organis: Is there a way to call fla from HTML?

Comment: Let me ask, what is that you are trying to achieve that requires AS3 and cannot be done in JavaScript?

Comment: I am using CasparCG server that supports only flash and HTML templates.

Comment: If you are doing it for your own amusement, well, go on and use **ExternalInterface** which allows AS3 and HTML/JS to communicate both ways (e.g. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-communicate-between-flash-and-javascript--active-3370). Yet if you are building something for other people to see, you should change your technology stack (server too) as **Flash** applications won't run for random people because of, yes, **EOL** (the whole point of which is exactly **Flash** not running for the majority of users).